# The video_player plugin fails to play videos - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I updated my flutter to 1.22.0 and now my video_player giving me Exception errors. It was working fine before I updated my flutter to 1.22.0.

Here is my error:

> E/flutter ( 8545): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception:
> 'package:flutter/src/services/message_codec.dart': Failed assertion:
> line 111 pos 15: 'code != null': is not true. E/flutter ( 8545): #0
> _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39) E/flutter ( 8545): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew
> (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5) E/flutter ( 8545): #2
> new PlatformException
> (package:flutter/src/services/message_codec.dart:111:15) E/flutter (
> 8545): #3      VideoPlayerApi.create
> (package:video_player_platform_interface/messages.dart:205:13)
> E/flutter ( 8545):  E/flutter ( 8545): #4
> MethodChannelVideoPlayer.create
> (package:video_player_platform_interface/method_channel_video_player.dart:46:42)
> E/flutter ( 8545): #5      VideoPlayerController.initialize
> (package:video_player/video_player.dart:275:45) E/flutter ( 8545): #6
> _ScreenBackgroundVideoState.initState (package:flow/widget/background/screen_background_video.dart:17:9)
> E/flutter ( 8545): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58) E/flutter (
> 8545): #8      ComponentElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) E/flutter ( 8545):
> #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #10     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6236:32) E/flutter (
> 8545): #11     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #12     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #14     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #15     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #16     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16) E/flutter (
> 8545): #17     Element.rebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5) E/flutter ( 8545):
> #18     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5) E/flutter ( 8545):
> #19     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) E/flutter ( 8545):
> #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #21     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #23     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #24     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #26     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #27     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #29     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #30     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #32     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #33     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16) E/flutter (
> 8545): #35     Element.rebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5) E/flutter ( 8545):
> #36     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5) E/flutter ( 8545):
> #37     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) E/flutter ( 8545):
> #38     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #39     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #40     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #41     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8545): #42     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8545): #43     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class ScreenBackgroundVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenBackgroundVideoState createState() => _ScreenBackgroundVideoState();
}

class _ScreenBackgroundVideoState extends State<ScreenBackgroundVideo> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/vid/login.mp4')
      // set background video using assets for login screen
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      }); // background video will play as soon as the splashscreen is closed
    _controller.play();
    _controller
        .setLooping(true); // looping set to true for the background video
    _controller.setVolume(0); // volume set to 0 for background video
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.dispose(); // Dispose the controller after play is done.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _controller.value.initialized
          ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Need help to get this fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to downgrade my flutter version to 1.20.2 for my video_player to work.

If there was any other solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can downgrade video player to **0.10.11+2** instead of downgrading flutter if you are not using any of new features inside video player plugin.

You can find more details in here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66627

Comment: I did try this but the issue was the same, and so I was forced to downgrading flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I just upgraded the flutter version 1.22.5  and it worked

Comment: I was having same issue for last some days and updated the flutter version to 1.22.5 and it worked

Comment: Thanks for specifying the version you upgraded to.